# Rails 5.2 credentials throwing error

Tags: credentials, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-2.5

I am using `Rails 5.2.0` and `Ruby 2.5.1p57`.

I have introduced Rails ActiveStorage to my Rails application. I am able to upload/download file to/from S3 if I use AWS key-secret directly.

When I am running below command

`EDITOR="subl --wait" rails credentials:edit`

> 1: from /home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@creative_automation/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in  `decrypt_and_verify'
>   /home/nishant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@creative_automation/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:190:in`_decrypt': ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)

This is not my ubuntu system or gemset specific issue as I tried the same thing on other machine but still it is not working.

Thanks in advance.